# Need only tab bar in portrait mode and all viewControllers in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing an iOS app in landscape mode, except that I need the tab bar to be on the right side(vertically). I was wondering if I could display all the viewControllers(navigation driven app) in landscape mode and only the tabbarController in portrait mode?

In other words, can I set the orientation of all viewControllers to landscape mode and set orientation of only the TabBarController to landscape mode so that I can affectively make it appear on the right side?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but I would highly recommend to open the UITabBarController & UITabBar headers to get an idea on how a tabbar is implemented, and start creating/subclassing your own, instead of hacking the existing components together. You'll need at least a viewcontroller, an array to retain the viewcontrollers represented by tabs, a view to display the active viewcontrollers view and a pointer to the active viewcontroller.

The learning curve for writing your own viewcontrollers is much higher, but trust me, it is worth it.